# Load category parameters in mod_articles_categories

Tags: category

I'd like to access category parameters in mod_articles_categories - Each time needed parameters should be loaded from category assigned to module.

I have looked into module's php but there's nothing for category, there's just list of children.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have figured it out going little round the corner. Isn't there any easier way?

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.helper');
$categories = JCategories::getInstance('Content', $options);
$category   = $categories->get($params->get('parent', 'root'));
$attr = json_decode($category->params);
```